# Plotting multiple BeanPlots in 1 Graph

Tags: r

I would like to display n beanplots in one graph next to each other. I receive vectors of respective values from a for-loop. In each iteration a new bean plot should be generated an put right next to the former bean plots. I tried several ways.

1. Passing values as a list:

   ```
   allValues <- list()
   pdf("Values")
   for(f in files)
   {
     ...    
     ...
     values = getValues(f)
     allValues <- append(allValues, values)
   }
   beanplot(allvalues, what=c(1,1,1,0))
   dev.off()
   ```

This gives me strange results.

I also tried a data.frame
I tried adding the parameter "add=T" to `beanplot()` command and putting `beanplot()` inside the for loop.

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append` operates on vectors adding all the elements. It seems you want to add a new list to `allValues`. Try this:

```
for(f in files)
{
  ...    
  ...
  values = getValues(f)
  allValues <- append(allValues, list(values))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also got the same result using

allValues <- c(list(values), allValues)